# Optional parameters across C# and C++

Tags: c#, c++, .net, function, optional-parameters

I started thinking how Optional parameters work between a COM object(C#) and a C++ object(or any other language).

For instance, I have a COM object built with c# that has **DoSomething** which takes two parameters- par1 and par2. Out of which, par2 is made optional in method definition.

```
public void DoSomething(string par1, string par2 = "value2");
```

Now, how does C++ interprets **DoSomething** method signature? Will there be a code breakage at consumer level(C++) if I keep adding optional parameters in my COM object.

Any comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is breaking.  Defaults are applied by the caller, not the callee.

So you'll have to rebuild your C++ client program with the updated type library.  Forgetting to do so is *very* unpleasant when you use early-binding, it pops too many arguments off the stack.  The stack imbalance produces very nasty misbehavior that's almost impossible to diagnose.  So don't take a shortcut by not updating the interface {guid}, you'll regret it.  You get a good diagnostic only with late-binding (DISP_E_BADPARAMCOUNT).